# How to handle odd behavior when encountering trailing ampersand in URI?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Using a very slightly modified version of the default sample WebApi project, when sending a request to a URI like so:

http://localhost/testing/api/values?foo=foobar&

All unspecified parameters are explicitly passed to the controller as null, ignoring any default values. This means that for a controller function like this:

```
// GET api/values
public IEnumerable<string> Get(bool all = true, string foo = "bar")
{
    return all ? new [] {"value1", "value2", foo} : new [] {"value1", "value2"};
}
```

I receive this error:

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'all' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String] Get(Boolean, System.String)' in 'testing.Controllers.ValuesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}
```

This error is also ignored by any exception filters on the pipeline. Removing the trailing ampersand makes it work fine.

Some pentesters have deemed this to be a security risk, so I need to fix it somehow. I'd prefer not to need to go through all instances of controllers being called with default parameters and change them to nullable just to fix this not-really-a-problem.

So, how to do one of the following:

1. Catch this exception and replace it with my own
2. Reject URIs like this entirely
3. Some other solution that prevents class names from showing up in request output when this happens (Debug mode is off, it does this anyway)

Comment: What if you use nullable? `bool? all=true` and treat "null" as invalid internally?

Comment: Yeah, that works, but we have several hundred calls in our api solution that would need to be looked at and changed and tested, all because the default isn't being used properly when a malformed URI is used. I'm looking for something more global.

Comment: You can use a delegating handler to fix the URI.

Comment: You can also use an action filter to check the response, and modify it as desired if a 400 is being returned.

Comment: Found the delegating handler and used it to fix. Haven't dived into this section of the pipeline in years, so maybe this was a bit obvious, but oh well. I think this might be a bug in the webapi framework though, model binder shouldn't behave like that.

Answer (score 1):

`DelegatingHandler`s operate before the controller is called in the pipeline, and can catch this error.

This handler can be used to detect this specific issue, and, at your option, fix it so the default model binder works properly again, or throw an exception and complain about the URI.

```
public class AmpersandHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var uriString = request.RequestUri.OriginalString;
        if (uriString.Last() == '&')
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uriString.Substring(0, uriString.Length - 1));
            //return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Unparseable URI - Trailing &");
        }
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The handler should be registered in the `Register` function of the `WebApiConfig` static class (part of the boilerplate automatically generated when creating a new webapi project) with the following line of code:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AmpersandHandler());
```